# Tautological line bundle over geometrically ruled surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, intersection-theory

Let $S$ be a projective bundle $\mathbb{P}(E)$ over the projective line $\mathbb{P}^1$. Assume we are working over $\mathbb{C}$ and that rank$E=2$.
 Let $p:S \to \mathbb{P}^1$ be the projection morphism and $f:E \to \mathbb{P}^1$ the vector bundle morphism.

I've seen two different statement about $\mathcal{O}_{S}(1)$: in some books I found written that there is a canonical injective morphism $$0 \to \mathcal{O}_S(-1) \to p^*E$$

which if I correctly understood, should be described in this way: the fiber of $(\mathcal{O}_S(-1)\mathcal{O}_S(-1))_x$ is identified with $Span(x) \subset E_{p(x)}$ with $y$.

Given that $p^*E_x=E_{p(x)}$ we have a natural inclusion.

Other times, I 've seen declaring that there is a canonical morphism $p^*E \to \mathcal{O}_S(1)$ which I really am not able to see how to define.

I'm asking this also because of this fact. I'm trying to study intersection theory on the Hirzebruch surface $ S_n=\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(0) \bigoplus  \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(n))$. Here, there is divisor  $D$ defined as the image of the section $$\sigma : \mathbb{P}^1 \to S_n$$
 $$x \to [1 \ \  0]_x .$$

If I have correctly understood, the line bundle associated to $D$ is $\mathcal{O}_S(1)$ and we would like to prove that $D^2=n$. Now,in the proof I was looking at (which is the one taken from Vakil notes about algebraic surfaces), he uses the first sequence to get that $\mathcal{O}_S(-1) \cong p^*\Lambda^2E^* \otimes Q$ for some invertible sheaf $Q$. The problem is that calculating $D^2$ now gives $deg(\Lambda^2E^*)$ which is $-n$ and so I'm getting pretty confused and I can't see how to make the proof work

Comment: This will depend on what definition of $\mathbb{P}(E)$ you are using. Some use $\mathrm{Proj} (\mathrm{Sym}(E))$ and others use $E^*$, the dual. Grothendieck has taught us, at least in algebraic geometry, that what ever definition you use, tautological quotient is superior and works well even for coherent sheaves $E$. This is because tensor product is right exact (and not left exact in general).

Comment: I edited the question to make my doubt clearer(at least I hope that)

Comment: You still have not clarified whether you are using $\mathrm{Sym}(E)$ or the dual.

Comment: I have to admit I do not know the scheme definition: I'm using the complex analytic one, where $\mathbb{P}(E)$ is the projective bundle with fiber $\mathbb{P}(E_x)$ and transition map given by the one for $E$ looked as projective transformations.